# Socket.io - Redirects to index.html, not .php

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io

I have created really basic application on Laravel & Socket.io but I have a problem.
In root dir of app I have file **app.js** - here is code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log('Server is running!');
});

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //
});

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {
    //
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

And it redirect to public/ directory - ok, but he won't 'look' on index.**php** only on index.**html** - when I remove index.html, I have a blank page - where is problem?
Here is URL: http://socket.vertisan.usermd.net/

Comment: This sounds like a web server configuration issue, but there is not enough information to provide any meaningful answer. You need to go do some basic debugging, like checking your webserver and PHP error logs, and the HTTP response status code, to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding as to what the server you're operating here is doing, and what the server that serves your website is doing.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Could you explain in more detail? It was not until I started learning Socket.io

Answer (score -1):

Normally this happen when there is no configuration within the web server to handle index.php as a DefaultIndex. To fix this issue here is what you should do:

**Apache:**
in your laravel project root dir add a new file and call it .htaccess. Edit that file and add the following into it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**Nginx:**
in your location block add:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
```

Hope it helps, if you are using any other web server let me know and

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with this and nothing. I'll write to support of my provider and I'll write what they think about that (on start, I think, there is problem with app - it's my first app with socket.io, that's why I wrote here)

Comment: Why would the socket server have anything to do with nginx in the first place?